# Cant run cucumber feature files that use ruby stef defs, get gem version conflict

Tags: ruby, rubygems, cucumber

I am new to ruby and just got a rest service repo to my local machine. I installed proper ruby version via rbenv (rvm gave me issues had to implode it). When I run a feature file in IntelliJ I get gems version missmatch error.

I have tried gem update.

This is the error message
Deprecated: Found tags option '~@pending'. Support for '~@tag' will be removed from the next release of Cucumber. Please use 'not @tag' instead.
DEPRECATION WARNING: The factory_girl gem is deprecated. Please upgrade to factory_bot. See https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot/blob/v4.9.0/UPGRADE_FROM_FACTORY_GIRL.md for further instructions. (called from require at /Users/xyzuser/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:130)
Code:
  * features/support/env.rb
Unable to activate jenkins_pipeline_builder-1.9.0, because activesupport-6.0.0 conflicts with activesupport (~> 4.2.6), nokogiri-1.10.4 conflicts with nokogiri (~> 1.6.0) (Gem::ConflictError)